# Switching start up view controller Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Say for example if I have two buttons one for apples and one for orange, and I select apples and takes me to the apples screen. How can I make it for now on every time I run the app it will go to the apples screen?

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you see the existing questions on SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in viewDidLoad

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fruit"] != nil)
{

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fruit"]isEqualToString:@"apple"]) {

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:appleVC animated:NO];

    }
    else{

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:orangeVC animated:NO];

    }

}
```

and on Button Methods

on Apple button

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"apple" forKey:@"fruit"];
```

on Orange button

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"orange" forKey:@"fruit"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store information like this using NSUserDefaults.

You'd store a boolean `bAppleSelected` like this:

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setBool:bAppleSelected forKey=@"appleSelected"];
```

You can read it by accessing the default userDefaults:

```
BOOL bApple = [standardUserDefaults boolForKey=@"appleSelected"];
```

Answer (score 0):

On your app delegate you must have some method that instantiates the very first controller and displays it in a window. You can just create an "apples controller" and push it there

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserdefaults here,

```
NSString* fruit=@"apple";
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:fruit forKey:@"controllerName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

and insted of the name string of your firstview controller in appdelegate file use the above NSUserDefaults.